# Do we have offline Python documentation browser in Ubuntu repositories to have one "point of service" to read and search the Python docs and APIs?

Tags: 20.04, python, python3, programming, documentation

The question is in the title. As a use case one can imagine the situation about finding function basing on its known functionality.

I already know about Zeal which [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=zeal). It downloads documentation sets from Dash project. This is great but the Python versions differ from installed on system. They are usually newer.

The [DevHelp](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=devhelp) application do not know about Python libraries. The search on `pydoc3 -p 8080` does not work as expected. KHelpCenter does not know about Python. The [doc-central](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=doc-central) package seems to [be broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/doc-central/+bug/1926066) for long time. [dochelp](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=dochelp&searchon=names) shows only index from `/usr/share/doc-help` and does not provide full-text search.

What else should I try to have ability for reading and searching Python documentation offline from `/usr/share/doc` (and similar locations)?
My system reports that I have 467 folders there (`ls -1d /usr/share/doc/*python* | wc -l`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created Bash shell script for searching locally installed Python documentation on Debian-based systems (such as Ubuntu) and placed it [at GitHub](https://github.com/N0rbert/python-local-search).

> This script allows one to run first preliminary full-text search to get Python package name and way to read the relevant documentation in the HTML-format.
>
> It uses `aptitude` for Python package selection, `html2text` and/or `pandoc` packages to run the conversion from HTML to plain-text to get better search results.
>
> The script shows found local HTML documents in default web-browser and provides information about further methods of documentation reading - via DevHelp, DocHelp or web-browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the documentation for Python itself (installable from the `python3-doc` package which depends on the actual system Python version's doc package), then you can just run a web server from `/usr/share/doc/python3/html` (e.g., using `python3 -m http.server`). The Python docs use Sphinx, which supports client-side searching.

Example using 18.04:

- The index page:

  [image]

  The sidebar links are mostly external.
- The reference section:

  [image]
- Searching:

  [image]

Comment: Great, but what about all python libraries in folders like `/usr/share/doc/python3-*` ? And search for all functions in for example SciPy, NumPy and so on...

Comment: Depends on what formats those are in. Sphinx-based documentation is pretty common in Python, but of course it's not mandated.

Comment: [NumPy's docs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/python-numpy-doc/filelist) also use Sphinx, so you can do the same from `/usr/share/doc/python-numpy-doc/html/`. The same is true for [SciPy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/python-scipy-doc/filelist) too, I think.

Comment: What is interesting is that only 15 of installed libraries ship html-based help (this number is from `find /usr/share/doc/*python* -type f -name *.html | awk -F/ '{print $5}' | sort -u | wc -l`). My main need is global user-friendly search from the single interface.

Comment: For that, all I can say is good luck. If it were a language like Go, there might be some hope, since Go has a standard method for documentation. But there's no such standard in Python, and even in the case of Sphinx, I don't think it's possible to merge already built documentation indexes.